# Is it possible to find a new variable Y such that a non-Markovian random variable X becomes Markovian?

Tags: markov-chains

It is given that $$X_n = \min(X_{n-1}, X_{n-2}) + \epsilon_n \quad \forall n\ge2 $$

where $X_0=X_1=0$, and $\{\epsilon_n:n\ge2\}$ are *i.i.d* random variables equal to either -1 or 1 with probability $1/2$.

The question asks if $(X_n:n\ge0)$ is a Markov chain. If not, construct a new stochastic process $(Y_n:n\ge0)$ such that

(i) $(Y_n:n\ge0)$ is a Markov chain, and

(ii) for every $n\ge0$, $X_n$ can be identified if $Y_n$ is known

### My attempt to solve this problem

$(X_n:n\ge0)$ is not a Markov chain becuase when we subsititue $X_3=\min(\epsilon_2,0)+\epsilon_3$ and $X_2=\epsilon_2$ into $X_4$, we get: $$X_4 = \min(\min(\epsilon_2,0)+\epsilon_3),\epsilon_2)+\epsilon_4$$
which depends on the previous two time-steps.

Now, if we want to know $X_n$, we need to know $\epsilon_{n-1}$ and $\epsilon_{n-2}$.
Possible well-known Markovian $Y_n$ are

1. $Y_n = \sum^n_2(\epsilon_i)$ and
2. $Y_n =\min(\epsilon_{n-1},\epsilon_{n-2},...,\epsilon_1)$

However, knowing $Y_n$ in these cases won't get $\epsilon_{n-1}$ and $\epsilon_{n-2}$ explicitly, and $X_n$ cannot be determined without knowing exactly what $\epsilon_{n-1}$ and $\epsilon_{n-2}$ are.

To get a more explicit knowledge on $\epsilon_{n-1}$ and $\epsilon_{n-2}$, we need to have something like
$$Y_n =\epsilon_{n-1}+\epsilon_{n-2}$$

Then if $Y_n = 2$, we know that $\epsilon_{n-1}=\epsilon_{n-2}=1$;

if $Y_n = -2$, $\epsilon_{n-1}=\epsilon_{n-2}=-1$;

if $Y_n = 0$, one of the $\epsilon$ is 1 and -1 for the other one.

However, this $Y_n$ is not Markovian in this case.

Can anyone gives me some hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original process $X_n = \min(X_{n-1}, X_{n-2}) + \epsilon_n$ is a *second order Markov chain*, where each state depends on the previous *two* states.  Such $k$-th order Markov chains can be converted into normal (first order) Markov chains by replacing each state of the original chain with an $k$-element vector/tuple containing the original state *and* the other $k-1$ previous states that the next state will depend on.

In your example, the first order version of your chain would have states consisting of the pairs $Y_n = (X_n, X'_n)$, with the initial state $Y_1 = (X_1, X'_1) = (0, 0)$ and the update rule: $$\begin{aligned} X_n &= \min(X_{n-1}, X'_{n-1}) + \epsilon_n \\ X'_n &= X_{n-1}. \end{aligned}$$

(I deliberately reused the symbol $X_n$ here, since the $n$-th state of your original second order chain will indeed simply be equal to the first component of the state vector $Y_n$.  You can easily verify this just by substituting the second line of the update rule given above into the first line.)

In the same way, if you had, say, the *third order* Markov chain $X_n = \min(X_{n-1}, X_{n-2}, X_{n-3}) + \epsilon_n$, you could turn it into a first order Markov chain by expanding the state into a three-element vector $Y_n = (X_n, X'_n, X''_n)$ and the update rule: $$\begin{aligned} X_n &= \min(X_{n-1}, X'_{n-1}, X''_{n-1}) + \epsilon_n \\ X'_n &= X_{n-1} \\ X''_n &= X'_{n-1}. \end{aligned}$$  The same mechanical conversion process can be applied to any higher order Markov chain with a dependence on some finite number of previous states.  (Of course, there's also nothing special about the $\min$ function here; it can be replaced with any arbitrary function $f$ of the previous $k$ states.)